# Hibernate Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Im trying to get the save of user to work.
Ive looked at many posts but everything what i try does not work.

My user class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Setter @Getter
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

private String username;

private String password;

private boolean active;

@Column(name = "session_id")
private String sessionId;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@LazyCollection(value = LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Work> workList;
}
```

My Work class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "WORK")
public class Work {

@Id
@Column(name = "work_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String adress;

private Date startDate;

private Date endDate;

@OneToOne
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
}
```

My UserDao Method:

```
    @Override
public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        transaction.rollback();
    } finally {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }
```

When i add a thing it works fine:

```
user.getWorkList().add(work);
```

But when i clear the list to remove all the records for the user i get an exception that tells me: `Column 'user_id' cannot be null`
And this is what i do in the code before calling saveOrUpdate: `user.getWorkList().clear();`

What am i missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the documentation here for many to one and one to many mappings: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association

The 'OneToOne' mapping on 'User' in class 'Work' seems wrong to me. It should be 'ManyToOne'.